# coverting byte array to string, back to byte array, back to string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I created random byte arrays, and then converted them to string with `String decoded = new String(myByteArray,"ISO-8859-1");` and then wrote them to some text file.

The result is that in the file i have lines of the form:

```
[-9, -18, 50, -124, -102]
[39, 112, -117, 5, 109]
[73, 111, 114, 107, -78]
```

etc.

Now I want to read a line from the file, and convert it back to byte array. I did this with the code

```
byte[] newByteArray = fileLine.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

I then printed newByteArray as a string with the code

```
String decoded = new String(myByteArray,"ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(decoded);
```

but it prints:

```
[-9,
[39,
[73,
```

instead of what we wanted which is the same as the lines in the file.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

**Writing to the file**

It is done via a class called MMULogger:

```
public class MMULogger 
{
    private static MMULogger instance = null;
    public final static String DEFAULT_FILE_NAME = "log.txt";
    private FileHandler handler;

    private MMULogger() 
    {
        try {
            handler = new FileHandler(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
            handler.setFormatter(new OnlyMessageFormatter());
            handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void write(String command,Level level)
    {
        LogRecord logRecord = new LogRecord(level,command);
        handler.publish(logRecord);
    }

    public static MMULogger getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MMULogger();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public class OnlyMessageFormatter extends Formatter
    {
        public OnlyMessageFormatter()
        {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public String format(final LogRecord record) 
        {
            return record.getMessage()+System.lineSeparator();
        }   
    }
}
```

the actual place where the method "write" gets the string "command" from is another class called process, the following lines are relevant

```
for(i = 0; i < currentCycle.getPages().size();i++)
    {
        String decoded = new String(currentCycle.getData().get(i),"ISO-8859-1");
        MMULogger.getInstance().write("GP:P" + id + " " + currentCycle.getPages().get(i)+" " + decoded, Level.INFO);
    }
```

where `currentCycle.getData().get(i)` is some byteArray

**Reading from the file**
Reading is done from a class called MMUModel with the follow relevant lines:

```
public void readData()
    {
        String commandAsString;
        try 
        {
            commandAsString = fr.readLine();
            while(commandAsString != null)
            {


                    byte[] pageContent = commandAsString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

                    listOfCommands.add(new GPCommand(pageContent));
                }
                commandAsString = fr.readLine();
            }
        }
```

I then return the pagecontent from the class GPCommand as a string and print it. this is the result you see above you with the partial brackets which we want to correct.

Comment: Can you show us the code which does the reading and writing?  This is where the bug is most likely.  Note: if you have the value 10 or 13 in it, the text will think this is a new line.

Comment: It's a bit of a problem since the code isn't really as simplistic as i wrote. I just wrote the general idea. In truth its a very complex system with many different classes. I'll try to edit it and give you a better idea.

Comment: You need to be able to reproduce the problem to say where it is.  All I can say from what you have shown is the bug is most likely somewhere else.  Note: storing binary data in a String is BAD idea even so.  If you have binary data, leave it as binary.

Comment: I don't have a choice in the matter I'm afraid. anyways I added the relevant lines of my code. hopefully its clearer now.

Comment: You do understand that the [*nnn*, *nnn*…] notation is not a magic format and is not actually parsed by the String.getBytes method, right?  Using your first line as an example, String.getBytes will return a byte for `[`, another byte for `-`, another byte for `9`, a byte for `,` (comma), a byte for space, and so on.  Your question does not make clear whether that is what you want, as you haven’t shown the results you expect to see.

Comment: That is what I want. The result I expect to see is the same as the log file. [-9, -18, 50, -124, -102] and so on

Comment: I had a byte array, I converted it to [-9, -18, 50, -124, -102]. Now I only have [-9, -18, 50, -124, -102], I want the original byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Base64 transformation to convert your byte into String and vice versa

With

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

You can do

```
byte[] bytedata = Base64.decodeBase64(stringdata);
```

And

```
String stringdata = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytedata);
```

## Edit : Using java.utils.Base64 Library

To encode byte[] into String

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();
String stringdata = encoder.encodeToString(bytedata);
```

To decode String into byte[]

```
Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] bytedata = decoder.decode(stringdata);
```

Comment: I get the error "The import org.apache cannot be resolved"

Comment: You need to download that library and include it to your project

Comment: Here is a link to get it [Common Codec](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6)

Comment: java.util.Base64 is available in the JDK now.

Comment: Ah ok didn't know it yet

Comment: Ok I imported java.util.Base64, how does it help me? I now get an error message "Illegal base64 character 5b"

Comment: Have you initially encoded it with base64 ? Or does your data come from another encoding method?

Comment: Well before calling the **decoding** method (from String to byte[]) you have to make sure that the **String** data come from a previous **encoding** operation. Else, it will fail

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only improvement being `StandardCharsets.ISO_6659_1` instead of `"ISO-8859-1"`.

The sure sign is the missing final `]`.

So the printing must have gone awry. This could be a logger that formats its log records. *A matter of Who Guards the Guardians.*

Remove

```
handler.setFormatter(new OnlyMessageFormatter());
```

**Probably your logging call is wrong,** `record.getMessage()` delivering something wrong.

It should be something like:

```
Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "{0}",
      Arrays.toString(newByteArray));
```

I guess you did not use Arrays.toString, and your byte array was taken as parameter array, and hence only the first byte filled in the message. Though why `[##,`?

Comment: Not an option. I need it. Teacher's orders.

Comment: Also, i cant find StandardCharsets.ISO_6659_1. are you sure this is what you meant? even google doesnt seem to find many results about it.

Comment: Android has no StandardCharsets. On the standard java it contains Charset constants for all Charsets that are provided by the java SE. Other charsets are not necessarily available. Its usage prevents the need to capture the exception for not-available.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it.

There is no problem with Arrays.toString and there is no need for special encoding.

The problem is that that i had white spaces inside my brackets and i didnt notice it when i did split(" "). anyways its working correctly now. Thank you.